# Page looks different on localhost than in Intellij preview

Tags: html, css, spring, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

In my Spring app I have implemented form on my page and I don't know why it looks different when I run it on localhost from when i clicked in the Intellij chrome preview. The input fields should be one below the other rather than next to each other.

Here is the html and css file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>FoodiesHub</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/mystyle.css}" href="../static/css/mystyle.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nova+Square&family=Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
          crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-md">

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/" id="logo-lettering"><img id="logo" th:src="@{/images/fh_logo_white.png}" src="../static/images/fh_logo_white.png"
                                                                  width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block mr-1 align-bottom" alt="logo">FoodiesHub</a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-menu"
                aria-controls="main-menu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Przełącznik nawigacji">

            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="main-menu">

            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="navbar-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/"> Start </a>
                </li>

                <li class="navbar-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/users"> Użytkownicy </a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"> Przedmioty </a>

                    <div class="dropdown-menu">

                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/items"> Wyświetl przedmioty </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/create-item"> Stwórz Przedmiot </a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/my-items"> Wyświetl moje przedmioty </a>

                    </div>

                </li>

                <li class="navbar-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/login.html"> Zaloguj się </a>
                </li>

                <li class="navbar-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/create-user"> Zarejestruj się </a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>

<div id="center-form">
    <h1>
        Zarejestruj się
    </h1>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/create-user}" th:object="${dto}" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <legend for="login-field">Login: </legend>
            <input type="text" id="login-field" th:field="*{login}">

            <div style="color: red" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('login')}">
                Incorrect login (must be at least 3 characters long!
            </div>


            <legend for="name-field">Imię: </legend>
            <input type="text" id="name-field" th:field="*{name}">
            <div style="color: red" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}"></div>



            <legend for="surname-field">Nazwisko: </legend>
            <input type="text" id="surname-field" th:field="*{surname}">
            <div style="color: red" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('surname')}" th:errors="*{surname}"></div>



            <legend for="mail-field">Adres E-mail:</legend>
            <input type="text" id="mail-field" th:field="*{mail}">
            <div style="color: red" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('mail')}" th:errors="*{mail}"></div>


            <legend for="password-field">Hasło: </legend>
            <input type="password" id="password-field" th:field="*{password}">
            <div style="color: red" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}" th:errors="*{password}"></div>


            <legend for="address-field">Adres: </legend>
            <input type="text" id="address-field" th:field="*{address}">
            <div style="color: red" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('address')}" th:errors="*{address}"></div>


            <legend for="city-field">Miasto: </legend>
            <input type="text" id="city-field" th:field="*{city}">
            <div style="color: red" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('city')}" th:errors="*{city}"></div>


            <legend for="zip-field">Kod pocztowy: </legend>
            <input type="text" id="zip-field" th:field="*{zip}">
            <div style="color: red" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('zip')}" th:errors="*{zip}"></div>

        </fieldset>

        <input class="btn btn-dark" type="submit" value="Zarejestruj się">
    </form>
</div>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
html {
    height: 100%;

}

body
{
    background-image: url("../images/cool-background.jpg");
    min-width: 400px;
    min-height: 400px;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    padding-bottom:60px;    /* Height of the footer */
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

#logo
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-right: 2px;
}

#logo-lettering
{
    font-family: 'Nova Square', cursive;
}


#welcome-section
{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    color: black;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding-bottom:100px;
}

.img-container
{
    align-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}

.welcome-header
{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
}

#hi-1
{
    font-size: 75px;
}

#hi-2
{
    font-size: 35px;
}


#footer
{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: black;
}


.navbar
{
    background-color: black;
}

#center-form
{
    padding-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

#back-button
{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#form-list
{
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;

}

.table-center
{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

td
{
    border: 3px solid white;
    margin: 4px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

tr
{
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#custom-button
{
  color: black;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Any clue what can cause the problem?

Comment: It might be result of resource download failure for you CDN links, try replacing them with local ones and test it again,,,,, browser is the best and closest to the end user experience so if it works fine in browser you shouldn't be worried about the result

Answer (score 0):

The problem occured because the versions of Bootsrap I had in head was different to the version I was importing in the bottom page script.

After I changed this link :

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css">
```

to:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

it started working as It should.